# Windows title bar icon

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with setting the titlebar icon for my application.

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "../../res/Icons.h"

void MainWindow::Create(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"MainWindow";
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_MYICON);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_MYICON);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, wstring(Language::wText[1].begin(),Language::wText[1].end()).c_str(), WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Icons.h

```
#define IDI_MYICON 1000
```

Icons.rc

```
IDI_MYICON ICON "App.ico"
```

It compiles fine, and the icon is shown in the Taskbar, as well as in the executable file, but not in the titlebar.  The icon is a standard ico with dimensions of 32x32.  I have even tried using `LoadImage()`, but same result.

[image]

Comment: That's because of your windows style. It should be visible if you use ``WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`` Or you can use a combination of styles to match your needs to show the window icon

Comment: Well, i mean, icon is visible in titlebar but not the one which i want, only default one is displayed ( the one used when you dont specify any icons in your application at all ) but i want to use my custom icon and it just doesnt change in titlebar, only in taskbar and exe.

Comment: There is no real cue in the question why this would misbehave. It is usually the exact other way around, the taskbar/file icon not changing, Explorer caches icons and will remember an old one. You *are* supposed to use a small icon for hIconSm, one that fits better in the limited space of the caption. Why the large one fails to resize is not obvious.  Thinking out of the box, maybe it is in fact the old cached one you like and it is app.ico that you don't.  Google "reset shell icon cache" to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I just did it, deleted icon cache manually, and then with TuneUp Utilities but still same problem. Any other clues ? I also tried to create blank project, inserted only neccessary code lines to make sure there is nothing wrong with rest of my project, but same behavior, icon is set for taskbar and exe, but not titlebar, using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @HyperByter it's most likely because Windows stores that in a cache. Have you tried renaming that app and relaunching it? I have faced similar issues before

Comment: Tried both, not working, looks like it completly ignores that icon for some reason, tried changing icon dimensions to 16x16 using irfanview, no effect, tried using online converters, no effect, tried LoadImage instead, no effect, deleted iconcache.db in appdata, cleared cachce using TuneUp, rebooted, still nothing, got no idea what more to do.

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: [img]https://i.postimg.cc/BbZBxtnC/t.png[/img]

Comment: I'd highly suggest avoiding a window class named `MainWindow` Window class names can be global and there is a high chance that someone else is using that (because they don't care). Use something with your application name in it.

Comment: I gave up setting that icon, nothing is working so far, tried with another empty project, where i defined only window and resources, and same problem appeared, so i must be missing something somewhere, most probably that problem is not with code itself but somewhere deep in my system i guess.

Comment: You could try sending the window a [WM_SETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-seticon) message.  That works for me.

Comment: HICON hWindowIcon=NULL;
    hWindowIcon =(HICON)LoadImage(NULL, L"App.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    SendMessage( hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hWindowIcon );    
Finally this actually works, but problem is that it loads icon from file that must be in same folder, how can i make it load from exe resources ? i Tried changing LR_LOADFROMFILE to 0, but then no icon appears

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `NULL` to `LoadIcon`, you should pass the `HINSTANCE` of your application to load from your own resources.

Comment: It didn't work. i tried hinstance, null, getmodulehandle(null) but nothing worked, the only one way how i made it finally work after 2 days of trying was by calling WM_SETICON, but it only works when i load it from file, can't make it work by loading it from resources, even when i pass hInstance in loadimage.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your resources? What does `GetLastError()` say after `LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_MYICON)` ?

Comment: I used wrapper which i found on google to get string of last error and it says:
Couldn't find resource type in entered image file.

Comment: Finally i did it ! Completly removed Icons.h from my project, changed my Icons.rc to following:
1 ICON "App.ico"
and MainWindow.cpp:
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(1));
how it works like a charm !
but i still dont get it why it didnt work when i defined icon in Icons.h

Comment: Was Icons.h included in your .rc file?

Comment: It was not, because if i include it in rc file, i get Unexpected end of file error.

Comment: Icons.h needs to end with a blank line probably.

Comment: Yes, the resource file must end with a blank line, there will be an unexpected end of file found erro if not. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The resource header file needs to be used in conjunction with the .rc file (i.e. `#include "icon. h"` in icon. rc), otherwise the specific icon file (path is specified in the .rc file) will not be found. In addition, if "icon.h" does not end with an empty line, you will get an [unexpected end of file found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/resource-compiler-fatal-error-rc1004?view=vs-2019) error.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
wndClass.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON5), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);//PROGRAM ICON
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).